# Can I get the Upgrade Price when going from Vista Ultimate to Windows 7 Professional?

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I am currently running Vista Ultimate.  I have no interest in Windows 7 Ultimate.  I would like to go to Windows 7 Professional.  Can I still get the upgrade price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are eligible for the upgrade licence for Windows 7 Professional, but you just won't be able to do an in-place upgrade, you will have to perform a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the upgrade editions are not dependent on what previous version you have - only the fact that you have a licence of any Vista (or XP) edition.

(XP can not be upgraded, but you can still buy an upgrade licence).